# Why so many views?

Tags: discussion

It appears to me that there is something strange going on with the number of views for questions.. For example, this question got 465 views in 18 hours.

[Is there a mode to automatically update copyright years in files?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8104/is-there-a-mode-to-automatically-update-copyright-years-in-files)

That is quite a lot of views in short time period for this site.. Just out of curiosity, is this normal? I have seen that many question only get 5-10 views the first 5-10 hours, and then suddenly the next day, they have around 100 views..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question ended up on the multicollider (AKA [hot network questions list](http://stackexchange.com/questions)).

Once a question is on the list, it gets way more exposure than normal, and a hot topic like *copyright* is likely to cause exponential growth in views for a short period.

This happens (or used to) for questions about swear words on EL&U.

For more information see: [How do the "arbitrary hotness points" work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page/61343#61343)

Comment: Yes I think this should explain the mystery.. Nice to know :)